# C# .NET Web Service Asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, web-services, asynchronous

I'm trying to implement an API that performs some really lengthy tasks using a Web Service. I basically want the Web Service to kick off a thread that performs the lengthy task and leaves it running until it completes. The issue is because its an API I want it to be cross-platform. So my questions are the following:

- Is it possible to make asynchronous calls that do not require the client to be on .NET Framework? (It seems the Begin/End framework in place requires I return the .NET IASyncResult object) If so how can this be done? Totally unambiguous sample code would be amazingly helpful.
- Because there is no state preservation in a web service, can this thread be later recovered? In the event that the client wants to cancel the process this would be highly important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good place to start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480516.aspx

If you implement this pattern, from the client perspective, nothing changes.  You can implement a second web method to check the status of any running jobs you queue up in your async method.

From the sample code, modified somewhat to give you an idea of what you need to do (I don't expect this would compile):

```
[WebService]
public class AsyncWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
public delegate string LengthyProcedureAsyncStub(
    int milliseconds, MyState state);

public string LengthyProcedure(int milliseconds, MyState state) 
{ 
    while(state.Abort == false)
    {
          //Do your work.  Check periodically for an abort
    }
    return state.Abort ? "Aborted" : "Success"; 
}

//This state object is what you can use to track invocations of your method
//You'll need to store it in a thread safe container.  Add it to the container in the Begin method and remove it in the end method.  While it's in the container other web methods can find it and use it to monitor or stop the executing job.
public class MyState 
{ 
    public Guid JobID = Guid.NewGuid();
    public object previousState; 
    public LengthyProcedureAsyncStub asyncStub; 
    public bool Abort = false;
}

[ System.Web.Services.WebMethod ]
public IAsyncResult BeginLengthyProcedure(int milliseconds, 
    AsyncCallback cb, object s)
{
    LengthyProcedureAsyncStub stub 
        = new LengthyProcedureAsyncStub(LengthyProcedure);
    MyState ms = new MyState();
    ms.previousState = s; 
    ms.asyncStub = stub;
    //Add to service wide container
    return stub.BeginInvoke(milliseconds, cb, ms);
}

[ System.Web.Services.WebMethod ]
public string EndLengthyProcedure(IAsyncResult call)
{
    //Remove from service wide container
    MyState ms = (MyState)call.AsyncState;
    return ms.asyncStub.EndInvoke(call);
}

[WebMethod]
public void StopJob(Guid jobID)
{
     //Look for the job in the service wide container
     MyState state = GetStateFromServiceWideContainer(jobID);
     state.Abort = true;
}
}
```

As far as the client is concerned, they are calling a webmethod called LenghtyProcedure that will not return until the job is complete.

Comment: It's good information, but a bit outdated.  I think nowadays people like their web services to be more RESTy than SOAPy.

Comment: Actually, the assignment I have is to create a SOAP API...so this may be the direction I want to go in. I'm reading over the article quickly but it seems to be giving me the Begin/End pattern that requires the .NET object to be returned. I feel like I'm overlooking something though.

Comment: @Redian - if you are thinking that the IAsyncResult is passed back to the client in the example, you are mistaken.  The framework exposes the BeginXXX/EndXXX pair as simply XXX to the client.  The IAsyncResult that you return in your BeginXXX implementation is used internally by the framework.

Comment: So it just returns the result, without waiting for the asynchronous method call to finish? (My brain is pretty much exploding at this point - it's been like staring at an optical illusion for 5 hours). But then how do I track the asynchronous call if I need to cancel it?

Comment: See edits above.  There are many ways to do this, this is just one of them.  Good luck on your assignment - it's a challenging one!

Comment: Though not what I was originally looking for, I think this is what I'm going to end up using. I thought this was not the solution I was looking for but the more I look over it it seems like the best idea for what is available. Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if the solution changed 7 years later :) I would so much like to ask this question again but with 2018 context, where the service needs to retun a json because it’s being called by an Angular app

Answer (score 4):

Okay, back up a second.

If you want people to be able to call asynch, then they control and you just respond. If you want asynch work to be done on your side, then you need to institute a different pattern. One pattern is to set up a method that calls the work and then another method to see the status of the work. The first method returns some type of token/id that can be used to check the status on the other call. You then have a third method to pick up the results. This is all client driven.

You can, in theory, set up a callback mechanism, but the client needs to have a means of getting the answer, which is a service on their side. This is more complex, and less "public API" in nature, but it can work with clients.

The heterogenous nature of the system should not be a factor. And, you can institute both patterns, so clients that have a web service that can take the answer can fire and forget, while others poll.

The one downside of polling is you add more weight to your side, so set proper expectations and be prepared to throttle the guy that does something like this:

```
while(thread.NoComplete())
{
   pollTheCrapOutofService();
}
```

If you can get around heterogenous environs (open standards, et al), and can force .NET, you have other options, as Craig has mentioned.

Comment: The pattern you describe is exactly what I'm looking to do. Does it require the Begin/End pattern then or can I just kick off a thread in the web method? The issue I foresee with this is how to find the the thread to suspend/resume/abort it if the client calls such a method.

Comment: well assuming one call per user you could always store the thread id in a database.  then when the user calls stop you can send the kill with the id

Comment: If you are trying to just fire off work, you spin up the thread and wait for the return. The context, at least in most cases, should be in the request and response, so you can match the response to the request. If this is not easily matched to a key value, you will have to create the key value by storing requests in a database. Then, requests with responses will equal completed tasks (what gets polled for, so to speak). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

We use AppFabric Workflow services for this.

They're exposed as WCF services, so anything which can make a SOAP call -- or any other supported WCF transport -- can invoke them.

Persistence is included for free (if you set up a SQL Server), as is monitoring and administration, and .NET clients are generated automatically.

One potential downside: You need IIS 7+ and .NET 4.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with AppFabric. Ideally, the customer would be hosting the API locally, and whereas IIS comes on the versions of windows they will likely be running, would it not be a little much to ask them to host another service?

Comment: You're going to need a web server if you want to host a web service. AppFabric runs on top of IIS.

Comment: IIS comes with Windows Business versions as a add/removable windows feature. AppFabric would have to be packaged with an installer for the web service as well then?

Comment: Along with your service itself, yes. It's just an MSI. Or you can get it from the Web Platform Installer. Like I said, the more meaningful restriction is IIS 7. That means it won't work on Server 2003. You need Vista+ or Server 2008+.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make asynchronous
>   calls that do not require the client
>   to be on .NET Framework? (It seems the
>   Begin/End framework in place requires
>   I return the .NET IASyncResult object)
>   If so how can this be done?

Expose a REST API to your clients.  Then, you just need a layer of code that translates between your .NET asynchronous objects and the REST service.

> Because there is no state preservation
>   in a web service, can this thread be
>   later recovered?

You can expose a REST method that returns status of the operation, and another REST method that cancels your async operation.

For long running operations, I generally set up a Windows Service with a `ThreadPool`.  You can expose your IAsync API there.

The easiest way to expose a REST API on an IIS Server is with a simple ASP.NET MVC application.  You can execute your long-running asynchronous processes directly from the controller methods.

Comment: Can I trouble you for a link that might take me in this direction? If I choose it, I'm going to need to run the change of course (SOAP to REST) through my supervisors.

Comment: @Redian: Ah, I see; you're already using SOAP. Hmm, the documentation on creating a REST API using ASP.NET MVC is a bit spotty, so since you're not familiar with ASP.NET MVC, I will refer you to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/RestServiceAPI.aspx, which describes how to create a REST API with WCF. But whether you use SOAP or REST, the principle is the same: create a layer of code that translates between your web service API and your .NET long-running asynchronous API.

Comment: Well that shouldn't be a problem then. I'm implementing an API for a thread-based solution that's already been written. Essentially, that should serve as the interface layer then. That's what I was looking for. And if I set up a service with a ThreadPool I should be able to track down the thread?

Comment: Yes, if the thread-based solution has something in its API for accomplishing this. There are a number of ways to do it. One way is to hand a unique task token of some sort back to the original SOAP caller starting the long-running service (it can be as simple as a "task number"); they can then use that token in another SOAP call to interrogate the process for status, or cancel the process.